# Criar branch local a partir de uma branch remota

Tags: git, github, branch, checkout

Eu tenho uma branch na nuvem no GitHub chamada `x1` e eu preciso criar uma branch local chamada `xlocal` a partir dessa branch na nuvem chamada `x1`. Como faço isso?

Comment: Olá, Sena! Se uma das respostas abaixo te ajudou, escolha uma delas e marque como "aceita" :)

Comment: Devo aqui ratificar o que o Dherik falou, para que você marque como "aceita" a resposta que melhor resolveu seu problema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar uma branch a partir de outra da seguinte maneira.

Primeiro, faça o `git pull` para garantir que receberá a branch `x1` no seu repositório. Depois entre na branch `x1` usando o comando `checkout`:

```
git checkout x1
```

Depois, estando na branch `x1`, crie uma outra branch usando a opção `-b`. No caso, a `xlocal`:

```
git checkout -b xlocal
```

A opção `-b` especifica que uma nova branch será criada a partir da branch na qual está.

Comment: Valeu muito obrigado!

Comment: No mesmo minto 

Comment: @hugocsl upvotei para fortalecer os irmãos :D

Comment: Tmj na irmandade então rss 

Answer (score 6):

Complementando as outras respostas, segue uma alternativa.

Se o repositório remoto possui uma branch `x1` (que você não possui localmente), primeiro você precisa puxar esta informação do repositório remoto. Você pode usar `git pull`, como sugeriu [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435215/112052), mas este comando também vai atualizar sua branch atual, caso haja novos *commits* remotos que você ainda não possui localmente (por exemplo, se estou na *master* e faço `git pull`, a *master* será atualizada caso hajam novos *commits* na master do repositório remoto).

Se você só quer puxar branches e *commits* remotos, mas ainda não quer atualizar o seu repositório local, pode usar [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), que é o suficiente para puxar as informações da branch `x1` remota.

Depois as outras respostas sugerem começar com `git checkout x1`. Isso não está errado, mas vai criar uma branch local também chamada `x1`, que por sua vez estará "rastreando" a branch remota `x1`.

Mas pense bem, se você quer criar uma outra branch `xlocal` baseado na branch remota `x1`, será que precisa criar também uma branch local `x1` que só vai servir para criar o `xlocal`? Pois é isso que as outras respostas estão fazendo (não que seja errado, só que você terá uma branch local à toa, que não será usada para mais nada - assumindo que você quer fazer todo o trabalho em `xlocal`, pois acredito que seja este o motivo de criá-lo).

Sendo assim, você poderia simplesmente fazer:

```bash
git checkout -b xlocal origin/x1
```

Ou, a partir da versão 2.23.0 do Git (de 2019), você também [pode usar o comando `switch` em vez do `checkout`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/533866/112052):

```bash
git switch -c xlocal origin/x1
```

Assim eu digo que quero criar a branch `xlocal`, e que ela deve ser criada a partir da branch `origin/x1` (ou seja, a branch `x1` do repositório remoto). Aqui estou assumindo que o repositório remoto é o `origin`, claro ([é possível ter vários repositórios remotos configurados](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#_adding_remote_repositories), cada um com seu próprio nome).

Desta forma não é criado a branch local `x1`. E assim como indicou [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/435216/112052), na primeira vez que for feito o `push` você deve informar que a branch local está "rastreando" esta remota:

```
git push -u origin xlocal
```

Nas próximas vezes isso não será mais necessário, bastando fazer `git push`.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro dá um `git checkout x1`.

Depois já dentro da `branch x1` você vai dar um `git checkout -b xlocal`.

Isso vai criar uma branch nova a partir da `x1` com o nome de `xlocal`.

Apenas no primeiro `push` dessa `branch` nova você vai ter que dar um `git push -u origin xlocal` , mas depois disso é só dar `git push` que já vai ser feito o push direto.

`-u` é uma abreviação de `--set-upstream` que serve para a nova branch ser "rastreada" pela `master`, pois antes do primeiro push essa branch nova não existe na master para ninguém ainda.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Nova branch local com o mesmo nome da remota:

git checkout -—track origin/branch

Nova branch local com um nome diferente mas trackeada com a remota:

git checkout --track -b newBranchLocal origin/branchRemota

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).