# Qual a diferença entre "git switch" e "git checkout"?

Tags: git, checkout

Acompanho em alguns tutoriais e posts em redes sociais, exemplos de uso dos comandos do `git` e um deles foi o uso do `git switch`.

No exemplo que eu me deparei, apesar de não ter nenhuma explicação, foi feito a criação de uma branch nova usando o `switch`. Veja o exemplo:

```bsh
git switch -c feature/post
```

Pelos testes que fiz, a flag `-c` é para criar uma branch nova. Esse comando é "similar" (pelo menos analisando por alto) ao comando `git checkout -b feature/post` para se criar uma nova branch.

Para relizar a troca de branchs, foi feito:

```bsh
git switch master
```

Semelhante ao:

```bsh
git checkout master
```

Confesso que é bem raro eu ver exemplos com uso do `switch`, mas creio que deva ter algo interessante para ser mencionado em relação ao `checkout`, então eu pergunto:

- Qual/quais a/as diferenças entre `git switch` e `git checkout`?
- Quando usar um ou outro? (se vem ao caso)
- São comandos equivalentes (sinônimos)?
- Algum deles é ou vai ser *deprecated*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O `git switch` foi criado na versão 2.23.0 do Git (em 2019). As [notas desta versão](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt) dizem o seguinte:

> *Two new commands "git switch" and "git restore" are introduced to split "checking out a branch to work on advancing its history" and "checking out paths out of the index and/or a tree-ish to work on advancing the current history" out of the single "git checkout" command.*

Ou seja, é um comando novo criado, juntamente com o `restore`, com o objetivo de separar as funções "*mudar para um branch*" e "*mudar o estado de um arquivo*". Ambas as funções eram feitas pelo comando `checkout`, que fazia uma ou outra coisa dependendo do que você passava como parâmetros. Para acabar com (ou pelo menos diminuir) essa confusão, resolveram separar estas funções nos comandos `switch` e `restore`.

O `switch`, no caso, é para alternar entre diferentes branches (ou simplesmente "mudar de branch"). Ou seja, se antes fazíamos `git checkout branch` para mudar para um branch, agora podemos fazer `git switch branch`. Ou ainda `git checkout -b branch` para criar o branch e já mudar para ele, agora podemos usar `git switch -c branch` para fazer o mesmo.

Mas como já dito, o `checkout` acumulava funções. Por exemplo, se eu modifiquei um arquivo e ainda não fiz `git add`, eu poderia fazer `git checkout arquivo` para que as alterações fossem revertidas e ele voltasse para o estado no qual estava no último commit. Já `git switch arquivo` dará erro, pois `switch` só trabalha com branches (aliás, para trabalhar com arquivos [foi criado o `restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003030), ou seja, bastaria fazer `git restore arquivo` para obter o mesmo efeito do `checkout`).

Creio que a ideia de separar as funções é para deixar mais claro o que está sendo feito. Se estou mexendo com branches, uso `switch`. Se quero só mexer com arquivos, `restore`. Ter dois comandos separados, cada um com sua função específica, me parece mais claro do que ter um único comando que pode fazer um ou outro dependendo dos parâmetros.

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70454786) há uma tabela comparativa entre os comandos. Mas vale lembrar que - pelo menos hoje enquanto escrevo esta resposta - a [documentação do `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/2.37.3#_description) diz:

> *THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.*

Ou seja, por enquanto é um comando experimental e o comportamento pode mudar em versões futuras.

Acredito que o `git checkout` não vai deixar de existir tão cedo. Mesmo que o `git switch` deixe de ser experimental, ainda deverá haver um período em que ele coexistirá com `checkout`, até por questões de retrocompatibilidade (pense em quantos scripts devem existir por aí que ainda usam `checkout` por exemplo).

Vale notar também que no [commit que introduziu o comando `switch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d787d311dbd7a4104a9dde23b90ae24528a15cf9) tem o seguinte comentário:

> *The good old "git checkout" command is still here and will be until all (or most of users) are sick of it.*

Ou seja, não me parece que o `git checkout` vai sumir tão cedo. O `git switch` foi criado em 2019, e na data de hoje a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/2.37.3) (atualmente na versão 2.37.3) ainda não diz nada sobre ele ser removido ou ficar obsoleto.